# How do i complete The Ritual Bond in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I found a [link to my quest](http://www.wowpedia.org/Quest:The_Ritual_Bond)

I dont understand it at all. I am standing in front of "Keeper Karithus" but how do i breathe in the incense? I dont see the 3 animals i can choose? how do i find them? how do i choose them? I am completely confused.

Note: I am the night elf druid.

Answer (score 5):

Oh @#$%^& `in front of "Keeper Karithus"` meant the item i need to click on is on the floor in front of Keeper Karithus. Someone asked the same question online and while closing tabs i notice i one page i hadnt look at and saw the comment.

Answer (score 4):

You must first use the incense on the ground in front of the NPC by clicking on it. (As a future suggestion, look up quests on [WoWhead](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=13569) rather than WoWpedia, as the former is often more detailed).

After using the incense, you will be transported to a different "phase" of Darkshore, and there will be a Thistlebear, Stag, and Moonsaber spirit. You get to pick one spirit to get a "blessing", which affects the rest of your time in darkshore. The Stag is a 10% move speed bonus. The Moonsaber is 10% haste. The bear is 10% less damage taken.

This bonus is nice, but restricted to Darkshore, so don't fret overmuch on a "right" choice. You can only get one. After doing so, you can speak to the Furbolg nearby to complete the quest and receive your reward.

Comment: Specifically *because* the bonus is restricted to Darkshore, I'd strongly suggest taking the Blessing of the Stag. 10% Run Speed is the only one of those buffs that will continue to benefit you when you pass through the zone again at higher levels, whether traveling to someplace else, or to gather or do Archaeology or whatever else.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz do note that it doesn't stack with rogue / druid / paladin move speed talent and/or form bonuses.